# How can I extend functionality of a Direct Connect client related to chat? Is there any way I can get pyDC to work?

Tags: python, chat, p2p

I need to write code to reply when a particular message is seen in the hub chat.
I tried using [PyDC](http://pydc.sourceforge.net/) but was not able to get it to work, some problem because it expects old wxpython libraries or something. T

he command line one works, but as far as I can see does not support chat.  The GUI one tries to import shell from `wx.lib.PyCrust` but PyCrust has been renamed to wx.py.  I tried importing shell from wx.py then the GUI started but was unable to connect to any hub. The command line one connects fine. 
Is there any other way I can do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eiskalt DC++ QT lets you write scripts in QTScript.  I can use this to do what I need.